# How to fetch data from my own api using redux?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-thunk

I'm trying to fetch data from my own api using redux, but I get an empty object and have no idea why it happens. API was written using express.js and MongoDB. It works when I use postman. I also use redux-thunk. Could somebody explain me, what's wrong?
Any help appreciated!

Here my code:

Here's my actions:

```js
export const fetchClientsSuccess = (clients: any): FetchDataAction => {
    return {
        type: CLIENTS_FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS,
        payload: clients
    }
}


export const clientsFetchData = (url: string) => {
    return (dispatch: any) => {
        fetch(url)
            .then(response => {
                if(!response.ok){
                    throw new Error(response.statusText);
                }
                
                return response;
            })
            .then(response => {
                response.json();
            })
            .then(clients => {
                dispatch(fetchClientsSuccess(clients))
            })
    }
};
```

Here's reducers:

```js
const initialState:InitialStateType = {
    entries: [],
    loading: false,
};


export const clientsFetchReducer = (state = initialState, action: any) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case CLIENTS_FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS: 
            return {
                ...state,
                entries: [...action.payload]
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

And finally container:

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { App } from '../components/App/App';
import { clientsFetchData } from '../actions/clients';
import { AppContainerComponentProps, AppContainerState } from './AppContainer.interface';

class AppContainerClass extends React.Component<AppContainerComponentProps, AppContainerState>{
    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.fetchData('/api/clients')
    }

    render(){
        const {clients} = this.props;
        return(
            <App clients={clients}
            />
        );
    }
}


const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: any) => {
    return {
        fetchData: (url: string) => dispatch(clientsFetchData(url))

    }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state: any) =>{ 
    return {
        clients: state.entries,
    };
}

export const AppContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AppContainerClass);
```

Comment: try adding a chained `catch` to your `clientsFetchData`,  function might be throwing an error. sometimes if you don't set the correct `contentType` and try to convert it to json it fails, might be a reason,

Comment: @Anuja I added a catch, but it doesn't throw any error too

Comment: Such asynchronous request must have `async` and `await` otherwise you will not the response as functionality doesn't wait.

Comment: I added it, nothing changed

Comment: @arisha I think you need to debug step by step, 
1. check if the api call is going through and is returning data
2. check using [redux-dev tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd) if redux state is being updated
2. check if it is being returned to connected component

Answer (score 0):

I feel your request is going to `/api/clients` but there isn't any baseURL attached to it.

Can you please confirm `fetch` is actually calling a URL like - `http://localhost:4000/api/clients` and not just `/api/clients`...

Could you also try adding a `catch` block to your `fetch` call and a `return` keyword to your `respose.json`, something like so:

```js
        fetch(url)
            .then(response => {
                if(!response.ok){
                    throw new Error(response.statusText);
                }
                
                return response;
            })
            .then(response => {
                return response.json(); //<--- add return here
            })
            .then(clients => {
                dispatch(fetchClientsSuccess(clients))
            })
            .catch(err=> console.log("ERROR",err); // <------ add this
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I tried to use this url too and nothing changed, maybe the fetch function is a problem. But I don't get any error too

Comment: what is the url of your nodejs server??

Comment: http://localhost:4000/api/clients , I followed this url and api works correctly

Comment: then perhaps your `fetch` call in frontend should be calling `http://localhost:4000/api/clients`

Comment: yes, I changed it and now it calls this url, but I still don't get anything..(

Comment: could you please try making some additional changes as per my answer post (i have just updated it to include some things)

Comment: thanks, I added your changes, but it doesn't event log anything, also added async await when calling function, still doesn't work

Comment: it's strange, but everything started working when I wrote state.clientsFetchReducer.entries in mapStateToProps function instead of state.entries
And thank you a lot for your help!